Unable to load schema from \vscode\**\node_modules\@salesforce in Visual Studio
After installing Visual studio, I downloaded Salesforce Cli for Windows.
I can see in C:\Program Files\sf\client\node_modules

Also in C:\Users***\vscode\extensions I can see

-> There are not all the directories with the @
But when opening the sfdx-project.json file after the creating of the project
I have the error Unable to load schema from c:\Users***.vscode.extensions\salesforce.salesforcedx-vscode-core-61.12.0\node_modules@salesforce\schemas\sfdx-project.schema.json': ENOENT: no such file or directory
(I would think to copy the "@Salesforce" directory into C:\Program Files\sf\client\node_modules but the command SFDX:Retrieve this source from Org displays "No components in the package to retrieve")
Do you have any idea of ​​the resolution to apply?

You are not alone. I'd try downgrading the used Salesforce Extension pack of VSCode to 61.11.0.

I have try downgrading the used Salesforce Extension pack of VSCode to 61.11.0 but  it is not functionnal, confirm you it not functions for you also ?

I've just downgraded that extension to 61.11.0, reloaded all Extensions and a) successfully opened the default org, b) saved a changed class to the org. I'm quite sure I've used this version for a couple of days a couple of days ago anyway. For me it's fully functional. What do you mean by "it is not functional"?

Good for me also ! Thanks !

I was able to retrieve the code in the Sandbox and deploy a simple Lightning Web Component, so I thought everything was functional..
However, I tested with the use of an Apex method in the LWC js
import { theMethod } from '@salesforce/apex/SuiviTempPresConsultantCtrlr.theMethod';
There is an error because the path is not valid
(The directory @salesforce does not exist)
I am interested in any ideas for a resolution

Don't use the curly brackets around the imported method, they are default imports.

I am able to import the method in LWC and to display in the page ! There is no error now !

Glad it finally works :-) Generally VSCode plugin versions don't always work, they prioritize sustained progress over perfection. In case of problems with a new version, downgrading and holding on until the next release is the best way of dealing with this.

There is a bug ticket raised in github
